# Spring boot entity without persisting or db table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I was reading this great tutorial https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-1/

I have an entity "User" which I don't need a table for in the db, the User info will be retrieved from an API. The user has a relationship with an entity that has a db table "Role".

How can I use spring boot hibernate to build such a case:

```
public Class User{
    private Long id;
    .
    .
    .
    @ManyToMany
    Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Comment: you cannot map a relationship with an nonexistent entity in the database. if you are looking for user information from other side then database can't recognize user entity as part of its objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot make relations with a non managed entity, but you can write a service manually, and load the user and the roles for it separately (the user is a REST request, and the role is a query)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a Service (and Repository), which will retrieve, from the DB, the `Role`s associated with `User` & then populate them in the `User`.